# Regarding the shutter speed settings for the Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3

Tags: camera

I want to take a photo with a Raspberry Pi camera module at a shutter speed of 1 second, frame rate of 1 fps, and ISO sensitivity of 100, but when I take a photo, the shutter speed only goes up to 0.08 seconds and it is shot at 30 fps, and I can't change the settings. I'm at a loss for a good solution. Can you give me any advice? I am running the program below to check the photos, but the photos are not set as intended. I was able to record at a frame rate of 30 fps when recording. In the settings with picamera2, adding the frame rate causes an error and the settings cannot be made, so I am considering whether it is possible to make the desired settings using opencv, but I cannot find the answer.

(Current system environment)

Main unit: Raspberry Pi 4b

OS:

Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release: 11
Codename: bullseye
Camera: Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 NoIR Sony IMX708

OpenCV version: 4.5.1

picamera2 version: 0.3.16

program
from picamera2 import Picamera2, Preview
import time

picam2 = Picamera2()
camera_config = picam2.create_preview_configuration()

camera_config["main"]["size"] = (640, 480)

picam2.configure(camera_config)

picam2.set_controls({"AnalogueGain": 1})

picam2.set_controls({"ExposureTime": 1000000})

picam2.start_preview(Preview.QTGL)
picam2.start()
time.sleep(2)

picam2.capture_file("test.jpg")

picam2.stop()

Comment: please add the command you are using ... edit the question and add it there ... do not write a comment